# How do i ignore specific files in phpDocumentor

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

I am documenting a program i built in PHP with phpDocumentor. Everything is working perfect, but the documentation shows me i have close to 100 errors because it is reading a file that i use to upload files into my server, but i didn't create.
Is it possible to ignore that specific file that is giving me all the errors? This is the command that i am executing to generate the documentation file:

```
phpdoc run -d /var/www/html/myprogram/ -t /var/www/html/myprogram/documentation
```

The file i'm trying to ignore is located inside the `/myprogram` directory like this:

```
/modules/module1/uploader.php
```

I found some information about the use of `--ignore`, but i don't know if that refers to something specific with the directories.

Is it possible to write something in the `index.php` file that instructs phpDocumentor to ignore some files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`--ignore` flag](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#using.command-line.ignore) will accept a single filename (as well as directory names or glob expressions):

```
phpdoc run --ignore /var/www/html/myprogram/modules/module1/uploader.php -d /var/www/html/myprogram/ -t /var/www/html/myprogram/documentation
```

Or since it will accept a partial directory, it could be shortened to:

```
phpdoc run --ignore modules/module1/uploader.php -d /var/www/html/myprogram/ -t /var/www/html/myprogram/documentation
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, second one did the job for me :D

Answer (score 4):

*I hope, my answer does not get downvoted. I am including my answer here for future reference and for others who might get benefited out of this.*

Creating a `phpdoc.xml` configuration file in the project's root directory helps a lot instead of complicating commands by including multiple include/ignore options. One can easily bunch together all the required options in the file which will be read by `phpdoc` to help build the documentation.

For example, my project's `phpdoc.xml` configuration file is as follows containing `phpdoc` options:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<phpdoc>
    <title>App Plugins Documentations</title>
    <parser>
        <target>reference/docs</target>
    </parser>
    <transformer>
        <target>reference/docs</target>
    </transformer>
    <files>
        <directory>.</directory> <!-- Scan and parse all the php files except those found in the paths below -->
        <ignore>assets/*</ignore>
        <ignore>includes/gm-virtual-pages/*</ignore>
        <ignore>includes/app_virtual_pages/*</ignore>
        <ignore>includes/third-party/*</ignore>
        <ignore>includes/vendor/*</ignore>
        <ignore>reference/docs/*</ignore>
        <ignore>storage/*</ignore>
        <ignore>views/*</ignore>
        <ignore>index.php</ignore> <!-- Ignore all the index.php files -->
    </files>
</phpdoc>
```

This way you can include/ignore multiple paths and files; even specific files as in your question. All you have to do is include the `ignore` option with your file's relative path.

```
<ignore>/modules/module1/uploader.php</ignore>
```

Just run the `phpdoc` command in your project's root directory with `phpdoc.xml` configuration file in it.